# How do I get the BigQuery job IDs of queries run through dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

BigQueryIO.Read function would return a PCollection of TableRow, but how would I get the job ID for that query that just ran?

Probably there may be a way I could pass in a custom job ID, but I'm wondering if there's any way to read this information from dataflow job information itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the logging that is pertinent to the Read operation, the PTransform will log the BigQuery Job ID. See as an example, a testing job that I ran recently:

[image]